# Is there a way to pick certain data based on a keyword in Karate?

Tags: karate

I am working on Email Registration use case with Karate, where the user receives a registration email with a URL

I have this JSON response:

```
{
    "links": [
        "https://www.link1.com",
        "https://www.link2.com",
        "https://www.link3.com",
        "https://www.link4.com",
        "https://www.link5/go/there.com"
    ]
}
```

I would like to fetch the link which contains "/go/" in it and use it for my upcoming request as Given URL

```
 * def goLink = someLogic??
```

Apologies if this was asked or example is available. Appreciate it if anyone can redirect me to resources. What logic I can use to get URL which contains "/go/" only? Then use that as my Given URL?

Note: I tried to write a simple Java Helper class, however that didn't help either

```
//Java Helper
public static String fetchRegistrationURL(List<Object> myList) {
    for (Object el : myList) {
        if (el.toString().contains("go")) {
            myList.add(el);
        } else {

        }

    }
    return myList.get(0).toString();

}
```

Tried to pass this to feature:

```
* def utility = Java.type('Com.helpers.Utilities')   
* def urlList = response.links
Then print '--urlList ==> ', urlList
* def acceptURL = utility.fetchRegistrationURL(urlList)
Then print '--register ==> ', acceptURL
Then status 200
```

This also failed. Hoping to see if @karate has a simpler solution

[Failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYxYC.png)

Versions:

```
     <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
    <maven.surefire.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.version>
     <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
    <karate.version>1.1.0</karate.version>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a "filter" or "find" operation. Please read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#json-transforms

Here is a simple example that works. You can try paste this into a Karate test and study it.

```
* def response =
"""
{
    "links": [
        "https://www.link1.com",
        "https://www.link2.com",
        "https://www.link3.com",
        "https://www.link4.com",
        "https://www.link5/go/there.com"
    ]
}
"""
* def filtered = response.links.filter(x => x.includes('/go/'))
* match filtered == [ 'https://www.link5/go/there.com' ]
```

I've used the JS [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method above, but `karate.filter()` can also be used. `Array.find()` may work better depending on your requirement.

Comment: Wow! I wasn't expecting such a quick and great response. It works!

Yes, I noticed JSON transformers actually very powerful for this purpose. Will read further. Thanks, Peter

Note: I actually tried karate.filter(), but got an empty list. Might be something wrong with my JS function

   `* def fun = function(x){if (x.includes("go")) { return x; }}`
    `* def urlList = response.links`
    `* def acceptURL = karate.filter(urlList, fun)`

Comment: @aslanTest `filter` always returns an array. so you need to do `acceptURL[0]` etc, work with someone who knows JS well if needed